# Magento2 Working site suddenly Stop working giving 500 error?

Tags: magento2, http-error-500

I am a newbie in Magento2. I am working on a site which was working perfectly until last night. I have not committed any changes but suddenly my site is giving HttpError 500. What's wrong with my site Please refer me any solution. It's my first project in Magento2.

Comment: Uncomment Or write following code under below file,

app/bootstrap.php

CODE :

error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);

And check what is error actually.

Comment: The error is getting because of server issue.

Comment: Check with your admin once

Comment: @shivashankarm admin mean server provider?

Comment: Yes, Check it once

Comment: I got this following error:
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected ':', expecting ';' or '{' in /home/petpanic/public_html/magento2/vendor/magento/module-config/App/Config/Type/System.php on line 290

Answer (score 0):

Go to your magento root on your server and execute these commands.

```
find . -type f -exec chmod 644 {} \;                        

find . -type d -exec chmod 755 {} \;                         

find ./var -type d -exec chmod 777 {} \;                

find ./pub/media -type d -exec chmod 777 {} \;

find ./pub/static -type d -exec chmod 777 {} \;

chmod 777 ./app/etc

chmod 644 ./app/etc/*.xml

chown -R :www-data .

chmod u+x bin/magento
```

Comment: Did it worked.?

Answer (score 0):

You check the standard var/log, var/report folder for any script error. 500 error will come usually for any php library is missing or .htaccess file issue. If php related issue means, definitely it will be logged on log file. And meanwhile which application mode are you using? Please enable developer mode ( php bin/magento deploy:mode:set developer ) to check the issue more specifically.